# How to specify location in google map?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to specify location in google map, I have javascript codes work fine but I do know how I can specify location from php variable
Below are sample codes.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCqgya6hvq6zu3Z2xeT5xEGPPi5pY2ize4&callback=initMap"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
//I want to search this location in google map
$location="Kigali Rwanda";
?>

<script>
    var myMap;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.518903284520796,-1.450427753967233);
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  ,
            scrollwheel: false
        }
        myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: myMap,
            title: 'Name Of Business',
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png'
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map" style="width:500px; height: 500px;">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Please anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) in this case

```js
function initMap() {

  //var address = '<?php echo $location ?>';
  var address = 'Kigali Rwanda';

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8
  });

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
    },
    function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          map: map
        });
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
    });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Deep, that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use lat, lng to specifiy location. In case of country or state name you should get lat, lng of the location and define it in the code. insert the value of php variable in hidden input field. On running script get the value and process it.